# How can I control the order of destruction between two boost::thread_specific_ptr(s)?

Tags: c++, destructor, boost-thread

I have a class with two `boost::thread_specific_ptr` objects where the first is used to construct the second and the second must be destructed before the first.

Other than creating a wrapper class for the two objects so I only have one `boost::thread_specific_ptr`, is there anyway to force one to destruct before the other when a thread exits?